# Periodic table in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemistry

I have a major problem. I can't get [this source code to work](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/periodic-table-of-chemical-elements/). Everything needed is on the page. I didn't know about copyright, so I just linked to it.

I tried the source code. I got some errors.

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/bx/it' undefined
(Font) using `OT1/cmss/bx/n' instead on input line 344.

Overfull \hbox (315.4194pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 346--347

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
)
```

I removed the last subject called Diagram Title

```
%% Diagram Title
  \node at (H.west -| Fe.north) [name=diagramTitle, TitleLabel]
    {(Mendeleev's) Periodic Table of Chemical Elements via Ti\emph{k}Z};
```

and made `\documentclass[]{article}` to `\documentclass[]{standalone}`. Everything worked perfectly. Until I tried to open the PDF - nothing, there was an "error occured". Not in the compilation, but in opening the PDF. So there is build a PDF - but when I tried to open it, it says can't open the document, the document type basic document is not provided. But I am really sure that I can open a PDF-document - and I have made a lot of PDF's (all working) in LaTeX on this computer.

I know, that is not much information, but I would like to use the code to create my own periodic table.

Kind regards!

PS! I gave you all information I have. There is not an error when I compile, just when I try to open the document. But here is the LOG-file (if that would help), but I am not sure what is important and what not, so you get the whole one.

```
LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) (format=pdflatex 2014.8.31) 15 MAR 2015 23:18
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**system.tex
(./system.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cls
Document Class: standalone 2012/09/15 v1.1b Class to compile TeX sub-files stan
dalone
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2012/10/14 v2.6b package option processing (HA)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks14
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks15
\XKV@depth=\count79
File: xkeyval.tex 2012/10/14 v2.6b key=value parser (HA)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))
\sa@internal=\count80
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cfg
File: standalone.cfg 2012/09/15 v1.1b Default configuration file for 'standalon
e' class
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count81
\c@section=\count82
\c@subsection=\count83
\c@subsubsection=\count84
\c@paragraph=\count85
\c@subparagraph=\count86
\c@figure=\count87
\c@table=\count88
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
\sa@box=\box26
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks16
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box27
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
Package: pgfrcs 2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
))
Package: pgf 2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 91.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count89
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen103
\Gin@req@width=\dimen104
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks17
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks18
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks19
))
\pgf@x=\dimen105
\pgf@y=\dimen106
\pgf@xa=\dimen107
\pgf@ya=\dimen108
\pgf@xb=\dimen109
\pgf@yb=\dimen110
\pgf@xc=\dimen111
\pgf@yc=\dimen112
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read1
\c@pgf@counta=\count90
\c@pgf@countb=\count91
\c@pgf@countc=\count92
\c@pgf@countd=\count93
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2008/05/14 (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
Package pgfsys Info: Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def on input line 900.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2009/05/22 (rcs-revision 1.26)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2008/05/19 (rcs-revision 1.10)
)))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2008/07/18 (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count94
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count95
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2006/10/16 (rcs-revision 1.4)
))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1337.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1341.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1355.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1356.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1358.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1359.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1360.
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen113
\pgfmath@count=\count96
\pgfmath@box=\box28
\pgfmath@toks=\toks20
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks21
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks22
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count97
))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2010/04/09 (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen114
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen115
\pgf@picminy=\dimen116
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen117
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen118
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen119
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen120
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen121
\pgf@xx=\dimen122
\pgf@xy=\dimen123
\pgf@yx=\dimen124
\pgf@yy=\dimen125
\pgf@zx=\dimen126
\pgf@zy=\dimen127
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2010/08/03 (rcs-revision 1.24)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen128
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen129
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2008/04/22 (rcs-revision 1.12)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen130
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen131
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2010/09/08 (rcs-revision 1.34)
\pgfpic=\box29
\pgf@hbox=\box30
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box31
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count98
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2008/04/22 (rcs-revision 1.9)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen132
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2009/06/10 (rcs-revision 1.11)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen133
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen134
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen135
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2008/10/09 (rcs-revision 1.3)
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2006/10/11 (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2008/10/09 (rcs-revision 1.8)
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2008/04/23 (rcs-revision 1.11)
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2008/11/23 (rcs-revision 1.13)
\pgf@max=\dimen136
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count99
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2010/03/25 (rcs-revision 1.16)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2010/09/01 (rcs-revision 1.17)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box32
))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2010/08/27 (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2008/01/17 (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2009/07/02 (rcs-revision 1.3)
)))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2010/09/09 (rcs-revision 1.13)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box33
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2010/10/22 (rcs-revision 1.8)
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen137
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen138
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen139
\pgffor@skip=\dimen140
\pgffor@stack=\toks23
\pgffor@toks=\toks24
))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
Package: tikz 2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2010/05/31 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.15)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count100
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen141
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen142
\tikz@lasty=\dimen143
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen144
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen145
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen146
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen147
\tikz@figbox=\box34
\tikz@tempbox=\box35
\tikztreelevel=\count101
\tikznumberofchildren=\count102
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count103
\tikz@fig@count=\count104
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2010/08/24 (rcs-revision 1.4)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count105
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count106
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count107
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count108
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarytopat
hs.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2008/06/17 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.2)
))) (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/preview/preview.sty
Package: preview 2010/02/14 11.87 (AUCTeX/preview-latex)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/preview/prtightpage.def
\PreviewBorder=\dimen148
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/preview/prtightpage.def)
\pr@snippet=\count109
\pr@box=\box36
\pr@output=\toks25
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshape
s.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryshapes.code.tex 2008/01/09 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshape
s.geometric.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryshapes.geometric.code.tex 2008/01/09 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.geometric.c
ode.tex
File: pgflibraryshapes.geometric.code.tex 2008/06/26 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshape
s.misc.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryshapes.misc.code.tex 2008/01/09 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.misc.code.t
ex
File: pgflibraryshapes.misc.code.tex 2008/10/07 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.3)
))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshape
s.symbols.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryshapes.symbols.code.tex 2008/01/09 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.symbols.cod
e.tex
File: pgflibraryshapes.symbols.code.tex 2009/10/27 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.3)
))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshape
s.arrows.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryshapes.arrows.code.tex 2008/01/09 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.arrows.code
.tex
File: pgflibraryshapes.arrows.code.tex 2008/06/26 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshape
s.callouts.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.callouts.co
de.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshape
s.multipart.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryshapes.multipart.code.tex 2008/01/09 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.multipart.c
ode.tex
File: pgflibraryshapes.multipart.code.tex 2010/01/07 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.2)
\pgfnodepartlowerbox=\box37
\pgfnodeparttwobox=\box38
\pgfnodepartthreebox=\box39
\pgfnodepartfourbox=\box40
\pgfnodeparttwentybox=\box41
\pgfnodepartnineteenbox=\box42
\pgfnodeparteighteenbox=\box43
\pgfnodepartseventeenbox=\box44
\pgfnodepartsixteenbox=\box45
\pgfnodepartfifteenbox=\box46
\pgfnodepartfourteenbox=\box47
\pgfnodepartthirteenbox=\box48
\pgfnodeparttwelvebox=\box49
\pgfnodepartelevenbox=\box50
\pgfnodeparttenbox=\box51
\pgfnodepartninebox=\box52
\pgfnodeparteightbox=\box53
\pgfnodepartsevenbox=\box54
\pgfnodepartsixbox=\box55
\pgfnodepartfivebox=\box56
)))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarycalc.
code.tex
File: tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex 2009/09/04 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.6)
) (./system.aux)
\openout1 = `system.aux'.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 40.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 40.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 40.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 40.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 40.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 40.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 40.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 40.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 40.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 40.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 40.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 40.
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count110
\scratchdimen=\dimen149
\scratchbox=\box57
\nofMPsegments=\count111
\nofMParguments=\count112
\everyMPshowfont=\toks26
\MPscratchCnt=\count113
\MPscratchDim=\dimen150
\MPnumerator=\count114
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count115
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks27
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
Package: grfext 2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds) That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds) that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds) In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext) [.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext) \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 452.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
Preview: Fontsize 10pt
Preview: PDFoutput 1
LaTeX Font Info: External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font) <7> on input line 120.
LaTeX Font Info: External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font) <5> on input line 120.
(./system.aux) )
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
12990 strings out of 493304
258267 string characters out of 6139871
457413 words of memory out of 5000000
16206 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
4839 words of font info for 18 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
957 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
56i,7n,60p,434b,642s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
PDF statistics:
3 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
3 compressed objects within 1 object stream
0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
13 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: We are going to have some more to go on here: for example, do you get an errors in the `.log` file?

Comment: i just past, compile and view it

Comment: "some errors" isn't very descriptive. I just ran the document without error using pdflatex in texlive 2014

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have added all the information I have now :-)

Comment: @BasiliusSapientia They are not errors

Comment: As @david said, warnings are warnings, not errors. ;-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle but then I have no errors :/ ... but I can't open the PDF :/

Comment: Those are just warnings. Nothing worrying. Have you definitely created a PDF?

Comment: the table is too wide for the standard portrait page but the document works and pdf may be viewed

Comment: @cfr: what pdf viewer do you use? Sometimes I had problems rendering a pdf correctly. Especially *pdf.js* tends to mess up things (no offense).

Comment: If you are using `standalone`, don't load `preview`.

Comment: @CommuSoft I'm not offended but I don't see what relevance your question has.

Comment: @cfr I have definately builded a PDF. I can't open it, that is all. I have added the LOG-file now. But there are no warnings and no errors. Just errors when I will open the PDF.

Comment: @BasiliusSapientia ***Don't use `preview` with `standalone`.***

Comment: @cfr: sorry this question was meant for BasiliusSapientia. Made a mistake...

Comment: @cfr "If you are using standalone, don't load preview." Well that was the problem. Now it works. Thank you! Could you maybe make an answer out of your commend so I can close my question? Thank you very much!

Comment: @CommuSoft the standard Linux Mint Pdf Viewer :-) ... but the problem was that I used preview with standalone :-)

Comment: the log you posted logs `No pages of output.` so no pdf was made.

Comment: @CommuSoft Ah! Now it makes more sense ;).

Comment: It also means that your question was highly misleading as you were _not_ using the document that you linked to, had you used that document you would have got a pdf, as all the people commenting found when they tried it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Actually I tried both with the original code (article) and with standalone. The only difference was, that I got warnings with documentclass article. Couldn't open the PDF for article either. But that doesn't matter now - it works with standalone when I remove preview :-) ... thanks for all help here :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`standalone` and `preview` can perform similar tasks. Indeed, one configuration of `standalone` uses `preview`. You should not, therefore, load `preview` separately if using the `standalone` class. Either just use `standalone` and remove the line loading `preview`. Or load `preview` *via* the appropriate `standalone` option.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
```

Or, when applicable

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
```

By default, `standalone` uses `crop` rather than `preview`. These options are mutually exclusive so you don't want to be using `crop` with `standalone` and then loading `preview` which will likely try to do conflicting things (or the same things in conflicting ways).